# mysql_pconnect issues

Tags: mysql-pconnect

I have a problem with mysql db connection..
My application does a lot of queries to the database.
And loads results of the query in the page.
Before, I used mysql_connect for the connection. I separated 
it in a different file the connection and then just
include the file in my subsequent php files.

So it seems like, i open the dbase and query everytime.
The problem came when the server's max connection per hour to the db was set to like 50. then just a couple of tries in my page, it reached the max connection per hour. It turned out
I have not been closing my connections.

So i tried closing the connections every time my php scripts end. I am using AJAX (async calls) to php. The problem was still the same, just a couple of views and then it reaches the max.

So i tried using the mysql_pconnect(). In my wamp, i set the max connections to 2. It kinda worked well, but when transferred to server, in linux, the connection was set to 2 also, it again had the max connection problem.

Apache is used as the webserver. Its really frustrating.
Can somebody give light on this?

Thanks a lot :)